# Identifying the specific enum within the constructor

Tags: java, constructor, enums

```
public enum Batman
{
    Rat, Cat, Bat;

    private boolean isMatch;

    // Constructor
    Batman()
    {
        this.isMatch =  (this.compareTo(Bat) == 0) ? true : false;
    }

    public boolean isMatch()
    {
        return this.isMatch;
    }
}
```

For the constructor line I get the error:
Cannot refer to the static enum field Batman.Bat within an initializer

I am primarily trying to figure out if the specific ENUM can be identified in the constructor.
Also the reason I am thinking of saving the "isMatch" value, is that I don't want to evaluate what it should be every time.
I know form the very beginning, so I just want to save the value, and thus when a call is made it is not an evaluation
but simply passing the value back

I know there are other ways to solve this:

1. Modify the constructor to accept parameter:

   Rat(false), Cat(false), Bat(true);

   ```
   // Constructor
   Batman(boolean isMatch)
   {
       this.isMatch = isMatch;
   }
   ```
2. Change isMatch()

> ```
> public boolean isMatch()
>   {
>       return (this.compareTo(Bat) == 0) ? true : false;
>   }
> ```

Any advice would be great.

Thanks

Comment: You don't have to change `isMatch()` in your 2nd Example.

Comment: Your `isMatch` should simply return the value of the boolean field you setup for the Enum. It seems like you are trying to make your life unnecessarily difficult.

Comment: You can't do it. You are trying to compare against something that doesn't exist yet. I like your option2.

Comment: This question makes no sense!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From **[Book Effective Java](http://www.amazon.com/gp/search?keywords=effective%20java%203rd%20edition&url=search-alias=aws-amazon-aps)**:

> Enum constructors aren’t permitted to access the enum’s static fields,
>   except for compile-time constant fields. This restriction is necessary
>   because these static fields have not yet been initialized when the
>   constructors run.

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, you can not reference a specific Enum value in the constructor. The obvious solution would be to write this:

```
public enum Batman
{
    Rat, Cat, Bat;


    public boolean isMatch()
    {
        return this == Bat;
    }
}
```

(BTW, you don't need equals with Enum)

But if the evaluation `this == Bat` really bothers you, you can override isMatch for Bat:

```
public enum Batman
{
    Rat, Cat,
    Bat {
        @Override
        public boolean isMatch() {
            return true;
        }
    };

    public boolean isMatch()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This way, you have no comparison, instead you use methods overrided by enum values.

And a variation on this, just for the fun:

```
public enum Batman
{
    Rat, Cat,
    Bat {{
            this.isMatch = true;
        }};

    protected boolean isMatch = false;

    public boolean isMatch()
    {
        return isMatch;
    }
}
```

(note the notation`{{` `}}` and the fact that `isMatch` must be protected instead of private so the Bat instance can access it.)

Comment: Also, isMatch is not a very clear method name. I hope in the real code it would be something like isBat.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Yes in the real code the enum is MatchType and I forgot to replace isMatch with something more sensible

Comment: Thanks for showing the optional ways.  I am curious to know if the @Override, {{}} options perform better or worse than passing the value as an argument in the constructor option

Comment: I doubt performance is an issue at all in these kind of things. But for the record, these last two solutions use a synthetic class that overrides `Batman` just for the instance `Bat`. So you have one more class loaded in the runtime and the method `isMatch` probably would not be inlined by the compiler anymore. So *theoretically* it is slower. I would be very surprised if you see any noticeable difference whatsoever, but if there is, the first solution I give you is probably the best.

Comment: @CyrilleKarmann Thanks for that.  It is good enough to know the theory.  I am trying to learn the internals and oddities so that I can make use of things appropriately

Answer (score 1):

You definitely can't reference any specific ENUM in the constructor, since it needs to be created when you want to refernece it and you are just creating it!
I would go with option 1, as you make the particular knowledge you rely on external to the internal implementation of the enum itself.